# Networksx - Efficiently getting generator object results

Tags: python, generator, networkx

I'm working with a list of networks that is 36M rows long.  I've used NetworkX to calculate the Adamic_Amar index for all (u,v) pairs in the network.

```
gen_obj = nx.adamic_adar_index(Graph)
```

In order to iterate and get the results of the generator object, I'm trying:

```
[x for x in nx.adamic_adar_index(Graph)]
```

But even for a small sample of <10,000 node pairs, this takes .05s per item.

Is there a way to more effectively get the results of a generator object?